# Word or phrase for the heir's heir

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a more succinct way of saying "the heir's heir"? No-one says it like that so there must be a real word.

I looked up the meanings of heir apparent and heir presumptive. Heir presumptive can refer to several situations and is generally a kind of weaker, lesser version yet it doesn't fit for the heir apparent's future heir.

For a real life example, in the UK Prince Charles is the heir apparent and Prince William will be his heir. William could be called "the second in line to the throne". But what if you're talking about something different being inherited like a family company, where there's no throne?

Comment: My main problem with "second in line" is that it's too grand for a company or especially something like a house. But heir also has that problem. I think the difference is that you can be the "heir" to something like your parent's small bank balance, but "second in line" to me always implies "the throne" which is on a completely different level. So there must be a word on the same level as heir, but I don't know it.

Comment: Often people will use the expression 'next in line', even for quite ordinary inheritances that are nothing to do with royalty.

Comment: In a few sources, it is mentioned as "heir's successor".

Comment: @WS2 you're right, but "second" still seems so formal in comparison. Maybe it's just because with less important things no-one feels the need to talk about the next person to get it? It doesn't seem the same but it probably is.

Comment: @ermanen That sounds good, it's vague enough to apply to any situation but it only refers to one specific person, and it doesn't sound much more formal to me than just plain "heir". And it sounds a lot better than "heir's heir".

Comment: @user8674 I would say something like 'Those two individuals are the heir and the next-in-line' to the estate. It was relevant in the days of 'entailed inheritances' in Britain, a subject comprehensively dramatised in *Downton Abbey*.

Comment: How is "second in line" too grand? You can be second in line to use a bathroom stall.

Comment: @TheMathemagician It's true but it seems different. Second in a physical line vs a line of succession maybe. Could also be a British English thing as I would say and have heard more often "second in the queue" for that.

Comment: Is _next in line_ really the same thing as the heir's heir? Isn't the next in line the person who will inherit if the heir dies before receiving the inheritance in the first place? That would usually be the heir's sibling.

Comment: @Barmar Next in line just means the first heir. The heir's sibling might be next in line _to the heir_ though.

Comment: I think "heir somewhat less apparent" is probably the most accurate term.

Comment: "Second in line" and "heir's heir" aren't necessarily the same person.

Comment: In England, isn't there a title given to the heir of the Prince of Wales?

Answer (score 2):

"Heir's heir" is probably the most succinct phrase since it very accurately describes what you are referring to. It looks a little awkward and if you keep following the chain of heirs it can get hard to track the various generations. But "heir" does not have a pattern similar to "[[great]grand]child" — there is no "[[great]grand]heir".

There *are* some slightly relevant terms that can make the description easier to understand:

> [order of succession](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_succession) — An order of succession is the sequence of those entitled to hold a high office such as head of state or an honour such as a title of nobility in the order in which they stand in line to it when it becomes vacated. This sequence may be regulated through descent or by statute.
>
> successor — next occupant of position: somebody or something that follows another and takes up the same position
>
> [descendent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Descendent) — deriving or descending from an ancestor

One option, therefore, is to switch terms from "heir's heir" to something like "heir's successor." They are effectively synonyms but it does help readers understand exactly what you mean.

---

Phrases that do *not* work for various reasons:

> second-in-line — Second-in-line is not necessarily the heir's heir. It often *can* be but it assumes that the if the current heir was suddenly not eligible (e.g., died) then that person's heir would become the current heir.
>
> second heir — The second heir refers to the hierarchy of heirs *on the same tier*. The first heir could be the oldest male; the second heir could be the next oldest. This more accurately applies when the inheritance is not given to just one heir but is instead split across *all* heirs.

Answer (score 0):

I would say *prospective successor*.

Comment: This seems too much like heir presumptive. When I looked on google it seems to be used for a politician who is expected to win an election but hasn't yet and similar. It could be "the prospective successor to the prospective successor" but that's even more unwieldy than "heir's heir"!

Comment: I've heard it being used to refer to the succession process in family businesses. I specifically mentioned it because of your question's reference to the inheritance of family companies.

Answer (score -2):

**Patrimony**:   [Property or other legal entitlements inherited from (or through) one's
 father, especially if it has been handed down through generations in
the same family, birthright.](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enwiki/15144)

**Birthright**: [n. Any right, privilege, or possession to which a person is entitled by birth, such as an estate descendible by law to an heir, or civil liberty under a free constitution; esp. the rights or inheritance of the first born. [1913 Webster]](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/18391/Birthright)

Lest there be any . . . profane person, as Esau, who for one morsel of meat sold his birthright. --Heb. xii. 16. [1913 Webster]

The heirs are referred to as a **scion** or **heir at law**: "A person entitled to inherit property under intestate succession laws"

Comment: Patrimony and birthright were things I hadn't thought of, but they don't work for what I need (it's an elected heiress who will next pass on the position to her elder sister's daughter, so not a birthright, and matrimony is completely different). I also want a word that specifically refers to the heir themselves and not to their inheritance. I don't understand how "heir at law" means the heir's heir, all I find is about invalid wills. Scion is correct but too vague - in my example in the question, Prince Harry is equally a scion (and I think at least their cousins are too).

Comment: So you want a term for a primogeniture's heir that was delayed via the 2nd eldest child inheritance

Comment: No, it's not primogeniture, only by election (restricted to the family - not sure what this would be called - like a matrilineal tanist almost? but where the tanist's successors are chosen too? completely fictional anyway, I assume), the eldest was never in the running. I wouldn't expect there to be a term for this specific instance which is why I didn't mention it in the question, only what the word is for an heir's heir, someone second in line.

Comment: I know but I'm trying to clarify:  Was it the primogeniture who gave up her inheritance (sometimes done for tax reasons/lack of heir at the time of inheritance) or she was bypassed? Historically, English aristocracy is well acquainted with every minutia, and I'm researching from their experiences